# Limiting UISwipeGestureRecognizer Area

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm using a number of `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` as selectors for a menu. Since I have more than one I need to have a limited area of swipe detection. This is the code I'm using:

```
 var rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipe1"))

 rightSwipe.direction = .right

 view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
```

I've tried adding it to a UIImageView but it won't detect touches.

Comment: UIImageView default for userInteractionEnabled is false.  Set it to true.

Comment: Yeah @JonRose, Thanks. I had just figured that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isUserInteractionEnabled` for `UIImage` and `UILabel` is false by default. Set it to true.

As I know, you can't limit gesture area. But you can check location of gesture and decide what to do with it.

For example:

```
func addGesture() {
    let rightGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(someAction(sender:)))
    rightGesture.direction = .right

    let leftGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(someAction(sender:)))
    leftGesture.direction = .right

    view.addGestureRecognizer(rightGesture)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(leftGesture)
}

func someAction(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    let location = sender.location(in: view)
    if location.x > view.frame.width / 2 && sender.direction == .right {
        // do something
    } else if location.x < view.frame.width / 2 && sender.direction == .left {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm just using the imageView() option. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to add `.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`. Here's my code:

```
  var imageswipe = UIImageView()
  imageswipe.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
  imageswipe.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height / 4)
  imageswipe.center = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height / 2)

  var rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes"))
  rightSwipe.direction = .right

  imageswipe.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
  imageswipe.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)

  view.addSubview(imageswipe)
```